# MySQL adding a `status` field to union query breaks it

Tags: mysql, union

The following query works:

```
select * from
(select id, sender, null as recipient, amount, `timestamp`
from ethTransactions
where userId = ?
union all
select id, sender, recipient, amount, `timestamp`
from sofTransactions where userId = ?) b
order by `timestamp` asc`
```

Which produces the output:

```
|id|sender         |recipient  |amount |timestamp          |
|1 |ajdoaidjoiwjdaq|           |0.03222|2017-11-08 03:09:11|
|1 |opiyptropyirpyi|dqwuebhdnwq|1.02223|2017-10-08 04:09:11|
```

But if I add a status to both selects, it doesn't:

```
select * from
(select id, `status`, sender, null as recipient, amount, `timestamp`
from ethTransactions
where userId = ?
union all
select id, `status`, sender, recipient, amount, `timestamp`
from sofTransactions where userId = ?) b
order by `timestamp` asc`
```

and I get an output of 1 row containing only the `id` field with a value of `101` which doesn't even exist in my data. I put backticks around `status` thinking maybe it's a reserved word but it didn't help. How do I fix the second query to output the same data as the first (With added status field)?

Comment: Edited to be more complete.

Comment: if you run each second **subquery separately** what happens? (add outputs to question)

Comment: The outputs are the same as the data I already posted except each query outputs 1 row as expected (The 2 rows in the question). Both tables are populated with 1 row each and both those rows have the same userId as you can also see in that data.

Comment: well, I didn't include the userId in the data because I'm not selecting it but assume it's a value of `1` for both rows.

Comment: but the output now include `status`? (which we do not see in the question).... is that status column of the same or compatible data types? try reversing the order of the subqueries. & I have now run out of suggestion. good luck.

Comment: I fixed it. It turns out I accidentally used utf16 for one of the status cols. I realized it after importing everything to a fiddle where you can see the error if you try to run it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/81caffa/3

Comment: idk why my mysql didn't output this error

Comment: xendi: I'm pretty sure that MySQL Server did throw that error. I suspect that the client program *ignored* the error returned by MySQL Server, and blithely continued as if no error had occurred (pinky finger to the corner of its mouth Dr.Evil-style "I just assume it will all go to plan. What?") The "output of 1 row" was produced by some code from something *other* than the result returned from the SQL statement.